# how to open and read the uploaded document in the same script in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io

Anyone know how to open and read the uploaded document in the same script in PHP?

I have a form to upload the word file in **index.php**. Now, I upload the word document. It goes to the file called **upload.php** and upload it successfully. Now i am wondering that **How can write the code for open and read the uploaded file in the same script that means in upload.php**

I am very new to PHP. So, please help me and explain me the flow of process detailed. Thanks in advance.

coding for index.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>
           HTML Converter
      </title>

   </head>
   <body>      
       <h4>HTML Converter</h4>
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">

    Please choose a file: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />

 <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
 </form> 
   </body>
</html>
```

coding for upload.php

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    } else {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      $filedata = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo $filedata

    ;

    }
  }
```

Comment: Please show some code for both index.php and upload.php. Essentially, you only need a huge if wrapper for both files.

Comment: to open\read word documents you want PHPWord. https://phpword.codeplex.com/

Comment: <html>
   <head>
      <title>
           HTML Converter
      </title>

   </head>
   <body>    
    <h4>HTML Converter</h4>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
     
 Please choose a file: <input name="file" type="file" /><br />
 
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit" />
 </form> 
   </body>
</html>

Comment: coding for upload.php

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly try something like this for upload.php:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
  else {
    $new_file = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $new_file);
    echo "Stored in: " . $new_file . "<br />";
    readfile($new_file);
  }
}
```

On a side-note, if it's a Word file (.doc, .docx, etc), or any binary file for that matter, the output will probably look a little garbled.

Also note that there's no sanitation taking place anywhere, so the code in its current state is probably pretty unsafe (especially if other people besides you personally will be using it). Just a heads-up.